# SQL error 1113 even though table is created

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error 1113 for this which states that there are no columns in the table, even though I did initiate them, does anyone know why this is the case?

Also under " insert into P (Pid, pstring, Tid) " how do i set Tid as a foreign key for the Tid in the T table, so that I dont manually have to plug it in?

```
DROP DATABASE IF exists DB1;
CREATE DATABASE DB1;
USE DB1;
Create Table T;
insert into T (Tid, tstring)
values (1, "t1");
Create Table P;
insert into P (Pid, pstring, tid)
values (1, "p1", 1),
 (2, "p2", 1),
 (3, "p3", 1),
 (4, "p4", 1),
 (5, "p5", 1);
SHOW TABLES;
```

Comment: You are not creating any columns in your `Create Table P;` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating any columns in your `Create Table T;` or `Create Table P;` commands. To create the columns and add a foreign key, use something like this code instead:

```
Create Table T (Tid INT PRIMARY KEY,
                tstring VARCHAR(100)
                );
Create Table P (Pid INT PRIMARY KEY,
                pstring VARCHAR(100),
                tid INT,
                FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES T(Tid)
                );
```

You can adjust the size of `tstring` and `pstring` as required. The important thing in terms of creating a foreign key is that `T.Tid` must have an index on it, and the type of `P.tid` *must* match that of `T.Tid`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJ17tiVNWeuCqfRXftt1ME/0)

Comment: would i still have to insert the values using  "insert into P (Pid, pstring, Tid)" i was under the impression that this is how you create the columns, also what would i need to plug in as Tid in p for it to know that it needs to pull Tid from t

Comment: @user3663055 yes, you still have to insert the values the way you are doing so (see the demo). The only way to create tables like that is using a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) type command. If you want to use a value from `T` for `P.tid`, you will need to use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) type command.

Answer (score 0):

mysql/mariadb tells you what the problem is

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> Create Table T;
ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column
```